# Не убивается процесс из python

Tags: python, subprocess

Здравствуйте! Есть программа, которая создает процесс, который пингует адрес 192.168.1.1 и записывает данные в файл text.txt. А основная программа читает первые 4 строки из файла и выводит их на стандартный поток вывода, после чего "убивает" раннее созданный процесс и сама завершается. Проблема в том, что процесс не убивается. После завершения программы данные все еще записываются в файл text.txt.

```
from subprocess import *
import time

my_file = open('text.txt', 'a')
child=Popen(['ping 192.168.1.1'],shell=True,stdout=my_file) 
s=' '
my_file_2 = open('text.txt', 'r')
k = 0
time.sleep(1)
while s:
    k += 1
    if k == 5:
        child.kill() #пытаюсь убить процесс
        break
    s=my_file_2.readline()
    print(s.rstrip())
    time.sleep(1)
my_file.close()
my_file_2.close()
```

Comment: Странно, у меня почему-то работает :-)
Из какой ОС пингуете? Вообще, у вас есть 2 `sleep`'а, возможно, из-за них что-то успевает еще записаться в файл, прежде чем умереть.

Comment: @approximatenumber ОС - ubuntu, программа спит максимум 7 секунд, а данные продолжаются записываться в файл после этого времени

Comment: У вас файл дозаписывается каждый раз. Потому что открыт в режиме `a`. Поэтому, вероятно, вам кажется, что скрипт не останавливается. Если ваша цель, - пересоздавать файл с данными, то измените строку на `my_file = open('text.txt', 'w')`, т.е. в режиме для записи. [Подробней](http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio/#file_modes) о режимах доступа к файлу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процесс у вас продолжает жить, потому что `child` в вопросе это `shell`, а не `ping` процесс (`python` запускает оболочку, которая запускает `ping` команду). `child.kill()` убивает `shell`, а `ping` продолжает жить.

Не используйте `shell=True`. Если `shell=True` используется, то необходимо применять методы, которые убьют сразу всю задачу (группу процессов). См. [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).

---

Чтобы прочитать `4` строки из вывода дочернего процесса и убить его:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['ping', ip], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for n, line in enumerate(process.stdout, start=1):
        print(line, end='')
        if n == 4:
            process.terminate() # or use process.kill()
```

В зависимости от платформы, у `ping` могут быть параметры командной строки, которые ограничивают общее кол-во запросов (`-c`) и/или продолжительность работы (`-w`).

Если по времени хотите чтение остановить, то см. [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279)